# Adding multile row in the girdview

Tags: asp.net

Adding the row one by one in the button click..
(i tried but its overwirting the same row)

Comment: Rephrased the question title, and removed the capitals. Please don't shout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is in vb for you. Tested it, seems to work fine. Declare dt as shared

```
Imports System.Data

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

 Shared dt As DataTable


    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            dt = New DataTable
            dt.Columns.Add("Colum1")
            dt.Columns.Add("Colum2")

        End If

    End Sub
    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        dt.Rows.Add(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text)
        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        GridView1.DataBind()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Why is this solution marked as accepted? The thread started asked for adding rows, and this adds columns?

Comment: @citronas: You need columns to be able to add rows. The rows are added in the button_click event handler. But the actual problem @user304018 was having was that the datatable was being recreated after each postback. He needed to declare the datatable as static(shared in vb).

Answer (score 0):

A gridview should be bound to a datasource. You'll need to add a record to this datasource and then call myGridView.Bind() to bind to it.

Lots of info on MSDN about GridViews:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this...

```
   static DataTable dt;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Colum1");
            dt.Columns.Add("Colum2");

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        }
```

Comment: thanks...but here the data added in the first row itself...i want to add the data row by row....(here its overwriting the same row)

Comment: Have you tried the code? 

 dt.Rows.Add(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);

Adds a new row to the datatable.

Comment: '
        Dim dt As datatable
        Dim dr As DataRow
        '
        dt.Columns.Add("Name")
        dt.Columns.Add("City")
        dr = dt.NewRow()
        dr("Name") = txtName.Text
        dr("City") = txtCity.Text
        dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, TestingGrid.Rows.Count + 1)
        TestingGrid.DataSource = dt.DefaultView
        TestingGrid.DataBind()
        '


this is what i tried..

Comment: Where are you declaring your datatable? It needs to be outside your method. Declare dt as class scope. Create a new instance of dt in your form load and add the colums in form load like I have done in my example. Looks like you are creating a new datatable each time the button is clicked...

Comment: ya am created the new instance in the load event only..but here am using asp.net...every time when i clicked button the load event also fired...here am used not ispostback also...